# How to tweak login logo position?

Tags: control-panel

When I add the company logo it appears aligned to the left with a lot of space on the right side. How can I make it appear to the center?

I know that adding `background-position: top center;` to the CSS aligns it to the center, but I don't know where I can set this change permanent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this [Control Panel CSS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) to add whatever CSS you'd like.

Comment: This is better than I expected, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wish to use a plugin to manage your login logo, you can create a 300px wide transparent PNG and place your logo in the center, or wherever you'd like to position it.